# Type inference in a IoC container class, return type of the resolve method

Tags: python, dependency-injection, type-inference, ioc-container

I have a simple IoC class implementation:

```py
Abs = TypeVar('Abs', str, Type)

class MyContainer:
    _bindings: dict = {}
    _aliases: dict = {}

    def resolve(abstract: Abs):
        # something along these lines...
        abstract = (
            self._aliases[abstract]
            if isinstance(abstract, str)
            else abstract
        )
        factory = self._bindings.get(abstract)
        return factory()

    def bind(abstract: Type, factory: typing.Callable, alias: str = None) -> None:
        # something along these lines...
        self._bindings[abstract] = factory
        if alias:
            self._aliases[alias] = abstract
```

And I use it like so:

```py
ioc = MyContainer()

def some_factory():
    return SomeConcrete()

ioc.bind(SomeAbstract, some_factory, alias="some")

# Both work nice!
ioc.resolve(SomeAbstract)
ioc.resolve("some")
```

Now I'm wondering if there's a way to make my editor be able to tell what would the return type of a call to `ioc.resolve` be regardless of what type of `abstract` I use (Type, or str)?

Comment: The return type of `MyContainer.resolve` is the return type of `factory`, but statically the only thing you can say about that is that it's callable; what `factory` will actually return is only known at runtime, assuming you are allowing arbitrary callables to be stored in `_bindings`.

Comment: The same is true regardless of whether you use a string or type to index the dictionary.

Comment: @chepner so you're saying it's not doable? not even with the `Callable[..., T]` technique?

Comment: No, because the `dict` value type of the `dict` itself is not specific enough (nor can it be with the current type system).

Comment: Example: given `d = {'foo': int, 'bar': float}`, what is the type of `d[x]("9")` if the only information you have is that `x` has type `str`?